# Excel ACE.OLEDB: COUNTIF equivalent in query

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-query, aceoledb

I developed the following Microsoft Query in ACE.OLEDB:

```
SELECT 
    Name, Country 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM Table1 as T1 
     WHERE Name = T.Name 
       AND Country = T.Country 
       AND Description="Work"
     GROUP BY Name, Country) / COUNT(*)
FROM 
    Table1 as T
GROUP BY 
    Name, Country
```

The query works fine but it lasts forever to execute on over 90k records in Excel.

**Is it possible to optimize this query by using a `COUNTIF` equivalent?**

I image the query could be optimized if it worked like this:

```
SELECT 
    Name, Country, 
    COUNTIF(CASE WHEN Description="Work" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*)
FROM 
    Table1 as T
GROUP BY 
    Name, Country
```

In reply to suggestions to you the CASE WHEN, I tried a simple proof of concept query:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Description="Work" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM (SELECT "Work" as Description)
```

and I get an `Unrecognized keyword WHEN` error.

Comment: CASE WHEN does not seem to work in MS Query although I know it works in T-SQL

Comment: See my updated post - I get `Unrecognized keyword WHEN` error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count will just count things.  You should do a SUM

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Description="Work" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

If it is not work, it sums a 0, otherwise a 1.

Looking more at your tags, you mention Excel.  You might need to change it to

```
SUM( IIF( Description="Work", 1, 0) )
```

Comment: See my updated post - I get `Unrecognized keyword WHEN` error

Comment: @AnalystCave.com, revised for IF() statement via Excel for you to try.

Comment: I think you missed one `i` there. The function is `Iif`. Yep this works thanks for reminding me :) totally forgot about this. Make the correction and I'll mark as answer